# Flip UIAlertView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, core-animation, uialertview

I have not found a way to do this without using private APIs, which is quite a shame, as it is something my app and many others could benefit from. I have an UIAlertView with a Details... button on it, which I want to sort of 'flip' to the other side and show a different UIAlertView, much like [UITwoSidedAlertViewController](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UITwoSidedAlertController), but not using any private APIs.

First of all, is this even possible? I looked over the UIAlertView header, but I couldn't see anything relating to this. UIAlertView does inherit from UIView, so I suppose that simple view animation might just be the key, but as I said, I've never done anything like view animation flips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use one of the several UIAlertView replacements that have been created and then add the flip functionality yourself?

You can find a UIAlertView replacement here: https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

The flip can be created using a standard flip animation block via `[UIView transitionWithView ...]`